# huey django version compatibility

Tags: django, python-huey

I checked huey's documentation and searched online, but couldn't find version compatibility information of huey with django. Can someone please provide me this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Huey docs](http://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html#using-huey-with-django) say that it supports officially supported Django versions.

In May 2017, the [officially supported Django versions](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions) are Django 1.8 LTS, Django 1.10 and Django 1.11.